# How to access foreign key related tables field

Tags: yii, foreign-key-relationship

I am having two tables as:

**User**

- userid
- username
- securityQuestionId

**Securityquestion**

- securityQuestionId
- securityQuestion
- userid

Now in controller I am having action as=

```
public function actionCreate(){

     if(isset($_POST['email']))
     {
            $record=User2::model()->find(array(
                'select'=>'userId, securityQuestionId, primaryEmail,password,userId',
                'condition'=>'primaryEmail=:email',
                'params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email']))
            );

            if($record===null)
            {
                echo "Email invalid";
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "email exists";
            }
       }
}
```

So $record->securityQuestionId displays id. Now I want to display actual securityQuestion. In user2 model i have relation as

```
securityQuestion'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, ' Securityquestion', 'securityQuestionId'),
```

So how can i display actual securityQuestion.

Comment: You have the typo here: `securityQuestion'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, ' Securityquestion', 'securityQuestionId'),`. `' Securityquestion'` need to be replace with `'SecurityQuestion'`. I said it many times to you. If not try to debug and place result here.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables are a bit strange:
Since User has securityQuestionId we could think that User belongs to SecurityQuestion but you also have userId in SecurityQuestion  so SecurityQuestion  belongs also to User.

For me you should have:

**User**

```
id
username
id_question
```

**SecurityQuestion**

```
id
question
```

And in your models rules:

**User**

```
'securityQuestions'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'SecurityQuestion', 'id_user'),
```

**SecurityQuestion**

```
'user'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'User', 'id_user'),
```

Now to have the related SecurityQuestion:

```
$model = User::model()->find(...);
//display the related question
$model->securityQuestion->question;
```

Comment: We have few questions and a lot of users, one question could be assigned to many users... so question HAS_MANY users and user BELONGS_TO question.
Plz, fix your answer.

Comment: I got securityQuestion by using query  $sec=Securityquestion::model()->findByPk($record>securityQuestionId);                        $qns=$sec->securityQuestion;                                        But now i want to display this question in user model's view form and want to put textbox to enter answer of it. After user submit answer want to check it from database whether its correct or not. So    how to display this question in user model's view form. Please help me